# Where is Django base.html file? Add additional static style sheet

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I would like copy & use the admin/base.html file in my templates/accounts folder. So I can hopefully include one additional custom style sheet in the head.
I have used the:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
```

previously to locate & copy the user admin forms.
When I follow the path generated from the line above I now get a path to .py files rather than .html files.

[image: path to files]

[image: .py files]

Does anyone have a copy of the base.html file? Or can suggest the cleanest way to include one additional style sheet?

This is what I am trying to avoid if possible.

base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('MY SITE') }}{% endblock %}

<!--CAN THIS BE ADDED TO THE HEAD OF base.html-->
{% block body_head %}
<link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock body_head %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">MY SITE</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}` django will get first found file `base.html` in subdir `admin` in all template dirs, but if you want to look on source of `django.contrib.admin` base.html, you can find it in the:

```
DJANGO_PATH/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I found exactly what I was after in admin/base.html to add an additional CSS file to the <head> of base_site.html in my templates > accounts folder.

{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}<link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">{% endblock %}

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

To locate django's base.html file, assuming you are using Linux and virtualenv and
your virtual environment folder, py_env (your own virtual environment name) folder is inside your $HOME directory. Then the path to your base.html is:

$HOME/py_env/lib/python<your_version_of_python>/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin

For me, I use termux on Android and the full path to my base.html is:

/data/data/com.termux/files/home/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin

Comment: Indeed the approved answer isn't exact about the position. Assuming you're using venv als folder for your virtual environment, it will be ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows with Anaconda environment manager `django` and base.html path is

```
/c/Program Files/Anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```